# No gradients provided for any variable, Attention-based Neural Machine Translation, tensorflow-keras implementation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, attention-model

I am trying to implement an Attention-based Neural Machine Translation architecture in Keras. I  have encoder (Extends Model class), attention(layer class) and decoder(Model class) classes. Finally, I have a "combine" class (Extends Model) that combines all these models.

Here is the issue I am facing:

[image]

How do I provide gradients to all these variables?

I have spent days figuring out and trying other alternatives like using GradientTape, but nothing seemed to be working.

Comment: Is it possible to have a look at your model and in the way u are fitting?

Comment: You probably use some operations that do not allow gradient flow between the loss function and the rest of the model. It is hard to say without any actual code. Also, it is better when you paste the error as a plain text, so people having a similar issue can easily find that.